# Are function arguments guaranteed to pass on the stack?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Is it safe to assume that function arguments will be passed sequentially on the stack?

For example, is `foo` guaranteed to output `x y z` regardless of compiler settings?

```
void foo(int x, int y, int z) {
    int *vector = &x;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << vector[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

I tried this with visual studio and it did work, but I am not sure if this behaviour is guaranteed.

Comment: output: `1` `1373019244` `32767`, short answer: NO

Comment: Nope, this is undefined behavior in theory. In practice, `calling conventions` determine how parameters are passed and can differ on different platforms (when calling across APIs, what compilers do within a self-contain compiled unit can differ from call-to-call).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Close this as not a real question! Oh wait...

Comment: Also, even if you could read the stack in a well-defined matter this way, no it wouldn't print `x y z` on many real computers. `y` and `z` may be at `vector[-1]` and `vector[-2]` (depending on the direction the stack grows), or arguments may be passed in registers (with `x` copied to the stack to make it have an address).

Comment: This worked for me when I tried it, I was wondering whether or not this was always the case, and whether this is a safe assumption to make. I do not understand how this is off topic.

Comment: @remyabel People use similar techniques routinely in production code, mostly when writing debugging tools, assertions, exception handling etc. The OP may have encountered a technique like this in architecture-specific debugger source, and simplified it into seeming like a useless question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer - each processor type has one or more sets of calling conventions associated with it. That determines how arguments will normally be passed - generally in some combination of registers and stack locations.  And if a smart compiler/optimizer knows something about the context, it can override those conventions in specific instances, up to and including not passing (unused, etc.) arguments at all. (This makes things painful for folks implementing debugging tools ;-()

To make things more concrete - the conventions for ordinary intel processors differ depending on whether they are running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Comment: I believe you are wrong, the calling convention is determined by the compiler.

Comment: @HugoBurd he says so `the compiler can override those conventions in specific instances`. But fundamentally the platform defines a calling convention, and if the compiler wants to link with other libraries on that platform it has to conform to calling conventions on that platform (for both calling into system libs, and passing callbacks into them). Of course you can do calling conventions like you want internally until you cross an ABI to the system or other libraries, but using the system ABI has the advantage of being able to create libraries too(for all compilers that adhere to the ABI).

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: IIRC, I've seen instances where multiple competing conventions were supported on the same hardware, depending on something like the specific operating system (and associated tool chain).

Comment: @ArlieStephens yep, that's why I wrote "platform" instead of processor like you did. You can even have a different calling convention in kernel-space versus user-space (I believe that's the case for the PS3)

Answer (score 7):

Your program has *undefined behaviour* regardless of compiler settings.

You can treat `&x` as the address of the first element of an array of **one** `int`, and thus `vector[1]` and `vector[2]` are out-of-bound array accesses.

Answer (score 5):

The language does *not* make this guarantee. Parameters are often passed on the stack and in registers, or a combination of. This depends on the ABI and calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, writing it that way is **a *bug***.

(And a very *bad* one, too!)

Here's the number-one rule, IMHO:  *"say what you **mean.**"*  Don't try to be clever, efficient, or cute.  Don't assume anything about implementation; don't try to do an optimizing compiler's job for it.  Write more for your colleagues (and for your own future self) than for the computer.  Also, strive to make your code *maintainable.*  "Future proof."

If that means, say, "redundantly," "inefficiently," "inelegantly," writing "extra" statements to do something that could be "golfed" into fewer statements, *"who the whale cares?"*  (We're using hardware these days that can execute *billions* of ops per second.)  The only thing that people care about is when your code either doesn't work or when it breaks something else.

Simple ... *human(!)* ... **clarity** ... is ... Key. Write it *clearly,* and you won't go wrong.